# Unable to drop view, due to unfindable dependency

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, sqlcmd

I am tracking down a bug in a SQLCMD migration script, when dropping unused objects.

The error I receive is the following:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server XXXXXXXXXXX\XXX_DEV, Procedure vwEmployeeCompleteAll, Line 47
Invalid object name "vwTeamsLatest".
```

The script in question looks like this:

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.spPrepareDischarge
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS ....
/*a handful of other views being dropped*/
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.vwTeamsLatest
```

Interestingly enough, `vwEmployeeCompleteAll` has no dependency on `vwTeamsLatest`.
At first I traversed the object graph manually a couple of times to verify I did not overlook it in a cascade some levels down and then double checked using ApexSQL Analyzer. Looking at it from both point of views, neither file has a dependency on the other one.

After this I did a full text search for `vwTeamsLatest` and it does not appear in any used view, sproc or function.

Am I interpreting this error message wrong and vwEmployeeCompleteAll is not the right place to go digging?

The system in use is a SQL Server 2017

Comment: It sounds weird. My first guess is a typo or similar in the script (e.g., executing the procedure). I would suggest running the process manually on a test, one row at a time. Even better, using source control or similar to get it back to the original state, and run it all to the current row (e.g, 1st run has 1st row, 2nd run has 1st and 2nd row, etc). That way you can check which command is actually failing. Note that if it's saying `Invalid object name "vwTeamsLatest"` it suggests that view doesn't exist. Also check what line 47 in the procedure is doing.

Comment: That is what I'm doing- to the letter. It fails at the last drop view statement, as we do not use that view any more. That is why I am confused, that it lists it as a dependency in that error message.

Comment: OK. Just confirming, the error statement occurs when you do the DROP VIEW statement - not after actually running the stored procedure? (That's the way I read what you're saying). This next suggestion is a long shot - is vwTeamsLatest an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15)? If so, it is possible for query plans to use indexed views even if not explicitly specified within the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good nights sleep enabled me to get some distance and rethink my approach.

Of course if twas a dependency of `vwTeamsLatest`, that was causing the issue. If this view wouldnt have had any other objects, that depend on it, I would have been able to delete it.

The culprit was a co-worker, who updated a function, that was using this outdated view, to a new view, but forgot to update this scalar function in the upgrade script. So the source file and the actual database where not in sync. Once I updated the function the migration run smoothly.